# Error on sql syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this simple create table ?

```
create table dept(
dept_id int,
dept_name varchar(50),
cse_depts int,
cse_deptid int,
cse_dept int
)

insert into dept (dept_id,dept_name,cse_depts,cse_deptid,cse_dept)
    values(5,'executive',8,11,5),
    (12,'it',11,17,12),
    (64,'speciality',17,30,64);
```

I get error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into dept (dept_id,dept_name,cse_depts,cse_deptid,cse_dept) values(5,'ex' at line 9:

I'm going crazy but not seeing the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed **Semi-Colon** (;) after Create Statement

Try this

```
Create table dept(
dept_id int,
dept_name varchar(50),
cse_depts int,
cse_deptid int,
cse_dept int
);

Insert into dept (dept_id,dept_name,cse_depts,cse_deptid,cse_dept)
    values(5,'executive',8,11,5),
    (12,'it',11,17,12),
    (64,'speciality',17,30,64);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24855d)**

Comment: cant believe i miss that, this is what happens when you create 15 tables in one day,thanks